# JSON.parse is not working for converting JSON string to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Need help to convert below JSON string into JSON object.Even string JSON  is valid json (verified by https://jsonlint.com/).

JSON:

```
{
    "condition": "AND",
    "rules": [{
            "id": "amount",
            "operator": "greater_or_equal",
            "value": "900"
        },
        {
            "condition": "AND",
            "rules": [{
                    "id": "vendorname",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": "US BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION"
                },

                {
                    "id": "vendorname",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": "HANSEN SOLUTIONS  LLC"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: What is the error, what doesn't work? You've only got half a question.

Comment: `JSON.parse`...

Comment: Please add code runs converting.

Comment: Error in console log --Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Am I missing something? The title is that `JSON.parse` is not working, and the answers so far are to use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Sure it is the common way and should work for this example.

Comment: @OmChaturvedi I just tried this in chrome dev tools looks fine tbh http://imgur.com/a/LslsH

Comment: @OmChaturvedi can you please add exact your code and environment, Browser.

Comment: <script>
str1 = '{
 "condition": "AND",
 "rules": [{
   "id": "amount",
   "operator": "greater_or_equal",
   "value": "900"
  },
  {
   "condition": "AND",
   "rules": [{
     "id": "vendorname",
     "operator": "equal",
     "value": "US BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION"
    },

    {
     "id": "vendorname",
     "operator": "equal",
     "value": "HANSEN SOLUTIONS  LLC"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]

}';

str2=JSON.parse(str1);
console.log('json-object',str2);

Comment: Based on that code why bother with a string to turn it into an object? Just create the object. There must be more to it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Need help to convert below JSON string into JSON object.Even string
>   JSON is valid json (verified by https://jsonlint.com/).

JSON.parse(jsonString);
Is a pure JavaScript approach so long as you can require a reasonably modern browser.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Update:
Try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TheString))`

Comment: Thanks for your input...I am using chrome browser

Comment: You are welcome. This should solve your problem: `JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Comment: @ Spacemoose , I am already using JSON.parse.See the issue title

Comment: He probably was down voted because the title states "JSON.parse is not working" and his submitted answer is basically "use JSON.parse". Huh?

Comment: try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourString))`

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON string is multiline. Multiline string should be stored using template literals, otherwise use string concatenation to represent your string.

The below exmaple uses template literals. It is used to represent multi line string.

```js
var str = `{
 "condition": "AND",
 "rules": [{
   "id": "amount",
   "operator": "greater_or_equal",
   "value": "900"
  },
  {
   "condition": "AND",
   "rules": [{
     "id": "vendorname",
     "operator": "equal",
     "value": "US BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION"
    },

    {
     "id": "vendorname",
     "operator": "equal",
     "value": "HANSEN SOLUTIONS  LLC"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}`;

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

This is a single line string.

```js
var str = '{"condition":"AND","rules":[{"id":"amount","operator":"greater_or_equal","value":"900"},{"condition":"AND","rules":[{"id":"vendorname","operator":"equal","value":"US BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION"},{"id":"vendorname","operator":"equal","value":"HANSEN SOLUTIONS  LLC"}]}]}';

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted. This is the likely issue. But also not really sure why OP is creating a string to convert to an object when he could just create the object in the first place.

Comment: Even I am not sure What is OP trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just using

```
try {
      let obj = JSON.parse( string);
} catch( e) {
    // conversion fails
   console.error( e ) 
}
```

Comment: However, let is not available on some Browser. But typescript should work. ☺️